# How to add multiple models to cart Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Can you please help how to add items to cart. Rails Agile explains how to add products to carts through line_items.
Let's say my websites offers tourist packages, limo services, apartment rooms,some other deals.
Customer adds limo car, tour package, offers to cart and pays for it. 
Are they different models   model Package, model Limo, model Apartment and other models. if so when I add to cart through line_items(cart_id, product_id) I can't figure out how to add other models. Or Should I link all models to product model? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: you should first figure out your data model.  only then can you start thinking about adding items to cart.

Comment: Ken thanks for answer. Categories limo, tour, apartment but they have different attributes. I can't have one product model with different attributes. ex. Limo have color, tour location, apartment size. How to handle that.

Comment: When you are selling, you shopping cart should only care about the product ID.  It can use that product ID to get that products model in order to access all of its attributes.  You do not need to add the model to the cart.

Comment: You are absolutely right.I can assume everything is a product. Limo have 10 diiferent attributes than tour package. Should I create different models and connect to product?

Comment: You could create different models and link each model to a product.  And your product model can contain some common product attributes, like ID, Category ID, Price...  There are many ways you can approach this!

Comment: I will really appreciate if you can show me one example!

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need a different model for every product type.  You can break down the products into different categories.  So you would need just one extra model--a Category model.   Each product would belong_to a category  (and category would have many products).  In the database each product would have a category_id.

Like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :category
....


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
```

...

Comment: Ken thanks for answer. Categories limo, tour, apartment but they have different attributes. I can't have one product model with different attributes. ex. Limo have color, tour location, apartment size. How to handle that.

Comment: That would have been good info to put in your question.  Take a look at this article for your options:  http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html

Answer (score 0):

You mention that models are too different (in terms of attributes). Therefore single-table-inheritance may not be what you want. In this case use [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) to achieve this.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchasable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :as => :purchasable
end

class LimoService < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :as => :purchasable
end
```